# How can I switch Python 3.8 to Python 3.6 as default on windows?

Tags: python, windows, version

I got two versions of Python on Windows, and try to set Python 3.6 as default. Does anyone know how can I set it? Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'default`?

Comment: add python 3.6 to the system variables especially the "path" variable put on there your python path

Comment: If you mean the default file association for .py scripts, that *should* be set to the py.exe launcher. If so, and you want a script to execute with 3.6, use the cross-platform shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3.6` on the first line. The py launcher supports that as a virtual command. It will extract the 3.6 version, find a 3.6 installation in the registry, and execute the script via that installation's python.exe.

Comment: If you want the py.exe launcher to use 3.6 as the default instead of 3.8 when the script has no shebang line, then set the "PY_PYTHON" environment variable to "3.6". This also means that running just `py` will run Python 3.6. If you want `py -3` to also run 3.6, then set the "PY_PYTHON3" environment variable to "3.6".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the path variable. You can see this in a command window by typing

Path

at your prompt.

To update the settings,

Open the 'System' properties.
System Properties

Open Environment Variables
Path Variables

Highlight the 'Path' Variable and click edit.
Edit Path Variable

Edit the values for the Python entries, to point to the desired python version.
enter image description here

OK on all boxes, close any CMD windows open, and open new one. Python command should now reference the correct location.